# Trying to create multiple conversations to the same person/participant

Tags: sdk, lync, lync-2010, lync-client-sdk

I'm wondering is there someway to create more than 1 conversation to the same person?  We receive inbound messages through an SMS service and then forward the text message on to the user via a Lync conversation.  When we create the conversation we pass in some contextual information so that if the user responds in the lync conversation we can send the reply back to the sender via SMS.

My problem is that if more than one text message comes in from different people for the same internal user then the lync sdk is sending both message into the same conversation (which is the default behaviour for Lync) which means I lose the contextual info for the first message that initially created the conversation, also if the user writes a reply in the lync conversation I have no way of knowing to whom that message should go to.  Hopefully I haven't lost you....

I can't see a setting or property in the sdk when creating conversations to create a new instance of a conversation even if one already exists for the intended sip address.

Any suggestions?

troy

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem recently, it looks like the Lync (specificly the 2013 client, we had no problems before) automaticly merges conversations from the same user address.

If we set up a second conversation to a user from the same sip uri (our application endpoint), the first conversation will be terminated, and the second conversation becomes active. This is all seamlessly merged in the Lync 2013 client, you dont even notice.

The (crude but working) fix was to call [`Conversation.Impersonate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/hh384421.aspx) with a different uri for each new conversation. Mind you this only works when creating conversations on a Trusted Application Endpoint.